# Are all 2-colorable graphs bipartite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

I believe bipartite means you can split the vertices of a graph into 2 groups, where each vertex in the first is connected to all in the second (correct me if Im wrong) Does that mean every 2-colorable graph is bipartite? If not, what are some counterexamples, and an explanation why?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in fact bipartite is equivalent to 2-colorable.